# Malformed records are detected in schema inference while using azure synapse analytics

Tags: json, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am new to azure synapse and creating a pipeline where I have used dataflow in that my source is Multiple json files which is coming from ADLS gen2.
While creating source for copy data inside dataflow I am unable to load or import schema from my source json. Also in source options we have 3 types for document form i.e Single , array of document, document per line. I tried all but no luck.

Please find the error below

Details
Malformed records are detected in schema inference. Parse Mode: FAILFAST

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This [error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-troubleshoot-errors#error-code-df-json-wrongdocumentform) can occur if an invalid JSON document pattern is selected as a source or the dataset properties provided are not supported by the JSON dataset or the wrong document form is selected in source settings.

- Check if the incoming JSON document is supported to parse JSON files.
- Check if the dataset properties/encoding type given is supported by the JSON dataset. You can refer to the supported dataset properties of the JSON dataset [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-json#dataset-properties).

[image]

- Select the correct pattern of JSON document form under source options.

[image]

[image]